# Transfer data from Session storage to a text box using external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I have created 2-HTML web pages,

1. the user enters data and the data is stored in local/session storage ( js file 1)
2. data is retrieved automatically upon loading the second web page ( js file 2)

**Both the web pages are linked with each other. web page 1 has a submit button that links it the webpage 2.**

** javascript needs to be external **

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "local/session storage". Can you edit the question to show the relevant code?

Comment: it means that i need to save data either in local storage or session storage

Comment: You mean sessionStorage and localStorage then, right? What is your question?